# jQuery Sortable - Upon Creation

Tags: jquery

Upon creation of the sortable/portlets I need to set the position based on what is saved from within my database. So my question is how would one achieve such task?

I have the following to update the position(s) when a user selects their preference with the following and I know there is a `create` method on the sortable class, but just not sure how to get the positions to show from the database.

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".column",
        handle: ".portlet-header",
        cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
        placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all",

        update: function(event, ui) {

            // identify handle for item
            var handle = ui.item.find(".portlet-header");

            // get current html of handle
            var html = handle.html();


            var data = $('.column').sortable( "serialize", { attribute: "sort" } );

            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                url:        '/api/portlets/update',
                data:       { position: ui.item.index() },
                type:       'POST',
                success: function(response, ui) {

                    console.log('Success ');

                },
                error: function(response) {
                    console.log('Error!');

                }
            });
        }
```

Currently I have two portlets and the database looks like:

[Database Structure IMage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB6G8.png)

Comment: anyone willing to help a brother out on this?

Comment: Are you saying you want the items in your sortable to appear in order based on the `order` attribute on the records you're retrieving from your DB? Why not just apply a sort within the DB query itself or via your API method? Both would seem more efficient than doing so client-side after the fact.

Comment: I want the items upon loading to be shown in the order they are in the DB or if portlet id 1 is in order position 1 (2nd) that's where it should be shown when the page loads.